# jSignature, Signatures displayed twice on Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: android, jquery, html5-canvas

I've got a strange behavior in the jQuery plugin jSignature. I'm using it in a Android HTML5 WebApp.

If I enter a signature it's displayed twice. This behavior only appears on Galaxy Tab 3, it's working on all other Android devices and in all Browsers.

[Example Image](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=572A838A66323D89!4197&authkey=!APM4SIwieo_Us20&v=3&ithint=photo,.png)

The code I use is quite simple:

```
var fs = $('<fieldset/>', {}).appendTo(root);
var div = $('<div/>', {
            id: field.attributes.FieldId,
            name: property.attributes.GenericColumnName,
        }).appendTo(fs);

        div.jSignature({
            'background-color': 'transparent',
            'decor-color': 'transparent',
        });
        div.css('border-style', 'dotted');
        div.css('border-color', 'black');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a general Android problem on Android 4.x.

The only thing that worked for me on Phone Gap is:
Changing the Android Manifest:

set
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Other solutions you can check here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=35474